# PHP error in the COUNT(*) as num

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error  `Notice: Use of undefined constant num - assumed 'num'` my code is following

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];
```

how to fix this ?

i haven't got suited title so please don't min it an of possible change it to suited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AkhileshBChandran gave one correct solution. In the future, if you're referring to the column, you need to put it in quotes.

```
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
```

Comment: Is this going to work with mysql_fetch_array?  If he had used mysql_fetch_assoc I know it would work.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran `mysql_fetch_array()` returns _both_ numeric and associative keys unless you specify `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_ASSOC`

Answer (score 1):

`$total_pages = $total_pages[0];`

Comment: it working now but would you explain it so i can understand what it the problem?

Comment: Since you are fetching the result as an array, the first element would contain that 'num' field. So, we are accessing the first element using the index 0  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
```